# How can I display 2-byte letters from Oracle Database with Python?

Tags: python, oracle, utf-8, cx-oracle

I have just started learning python.
So I'd like to apologize for this low level question in advance.

The following code is to output data from DataBase on a message box, and when the data includes two byte letters(like a 'KANJI' or something), this error has occurred everytime.

```
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 11: illegal multibyte sequence"
```

How can I fix this problem??

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import cx_Oracle

def foo():
    HOST = "99.99.99.99"
    PORT = 1521
    SID = "XXXXX"

    tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(HOST, PORT, SID)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect("XXXXXX", "XXXXXX", tns)

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT ITEMNAME FROM MA_ITEM WHERE ITEMID='" + t.get() + "'")


    row = cur.fetchall()
    for r in row:
        messagebox.showinfo("RESULT", r[0])
        break



root = Tk()
root.title('My First App')
frame1 = ttk.Frame(root)
label1 = ttk.Label(frame1, text='ITEMID:')

t = StringVar()

entry1 = ttk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=t) 
button1 = ttk.Button(frame1, text='OK', command=foo)

frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=(N,E,S,W))
label1.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=E)
entry1.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W)
button1.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W)

for child in frame1.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

If someone tell me, I would be soooo happy! Thanks.

Comment: Please include the full traceback. At first guess, I'd say it's because you're using string concatenation to build your query string which you should not do. This is vulnerable to SQL injection and, even if you believe your system is isolated and safe, usually leads to issues that just don't occur if you do things correctly by default. Use a parameterized query.

Comment: At what line no you are getting this error? is it while printing message ?  I tried below code its worked for me                                                                            
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo("RESULT", "タ")

Comment: Start by specifying a character set when you connect to the DB: `connection = cx_Oracle.connect("XXXXXX", "XXXXXX", tns, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")`.  And review the cx_Oracle manual [Characters Sets and National Language Support (NLS)](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html).

Comment: I appreciate your kindness! Finally I made it to change how to connect, thank Christopher!! No worries, I fixed the vulnerable problem too, adopting a prepared statement.          Thank everyone!!